# In spring mvc portlet can one portlet/controller have multiple context.xml files..?

Tags: spring-mvc

I was asked this question in an interview. I said no then he asked then how do I access other portlet controllers. I am new to spring and what I know is that in application context file we have beans that are nothing but controllers and their corresponding dependencies...which are defined like below:

```
<bean id="projectProfileSummaryController" class="com.ca.beacon.implproject.controllers.ProjectProfileSummaryController">
        <property name="restTemplateBuilder" ref="restTemplateBuilder"/>
        <property name="implementProjectService" ref="implementProjectService"/>
```

along with their views that is defined in view resolver.

Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, one portlet can have multiple controller classes.

Second of all, according to [docs for FrameworkPortlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/FrameworkPortlet.html) (parent class of `DispatcherPortlet`):

> Passes a "contextConfigLocation" portlet init-param to the context instance, parsing it into potentially multiple file paths which can be separated by any number of commas and spaces, like "test-portlet.xml, myPortlet.xml". If not explicitly specified, the context implementation is supposed to build a default location from the namespace of the portlet.

So yes, one portlet can have multiple context xml files.